# YouTube API key isn't working in Magento

Tags: youtube-api, magento2

I've created a project and got an API key for YouTube. I've added this in to Magento via Stores>Configuration>Catalog.

I've saved and refreshed the cache. However when I go to add a video on the product page I get the error Error: "Video cant be shown due to the following reason: Youtube API key is invalid"

I can't see why the API key would be invalid, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://magenticians.com/add-video-to-product-in-magento-2/) takem from a [post in StackExchange channel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152600/video-not-found-while-add-youtube-video-in-magento-2). Try to check if you missed something in the process, also most important part is to make sure that you enabled the key.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've done that, the API is enabled and still, I get the error I don't understand how that could possibly be.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same issue. My key is 100% valid, the YT APIs are enabled and restricted to the correct domain. I am at lost here.

Comment: @Dynomite; same here now. Did you ever found something?

Comment: Same here too, magento 2 su**s!

Answer (score 0):

I got around this when I figured out it was a scope issue (at least for the version I am using). I was unable to save the API key in the default scope, so I created a new row in `core_config_data`.

Basically, you need a row like this:

```
config_id|scope|scope_id|path|value|updated_at
xxx|default|0|catalog/product_video/youtube_api_key|xxyourkeygoesherexxx|yyyy-mm-dd
```